# Bug on @XmlElementWrapper inside <xml-elements> MoXy?

Tags: eclipselink, moxy

I found a tricky bug:

If I define the metadata-xml-binding as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="package" xml-mapping-metadata-complete="true">
    <xml-schema element-form-default="QUALIFIED" />
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="SearchResult">
            <xml-root-element/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="count"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="requestParameters"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="pageSize"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="sortDirection"/>
                <xml-elements java-attribute="results">
                    <xml-element name="GaDictionaryElement" type="it.ga.model.GaDictionary">
                        <xml-element-wrapper name="GaDictionaryElementWrapper" />
                    </xml-element>
                    <xml-element name="OrganizationUnitElement" type="it.ga.model.OrganizationUnit">
                        <xml-element-wrapper name="OrganizationUnitElementWrapper" />
                    </xml-element>
                    <xml-element name="PersonElement" type="it.ga.model.Person">
                        <xml-element-wrapper name="PersonElementWrapper"  />
                    </xml-element>
                    <xml-element name="Empty" type="java.lang.String">
                        <xml-element-wrapper name="EmptyWrapper" nillable="true"/>
                    </xml-element>
                </xml-elements>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

I have seen that the `<xml-element-wrapper>` tag doesn't work because it's into the `<xml-element>` tag that is surrounded from the `<xml-elements>` tag. So I was looking to find a way to solve this problem in a clean way. Because I need an empty node when the `List<?>` results of my class is empty. 
A really bad workaround is creating a lot of different binding file as many type I have for the `List<?>` results but I don't like that! 
**Furthermore did someone try to create a binding file that could be useful for classes that implements a particular interface? E.g. In a way that I can see only the property of the object defined on the binding file and specifying as type the name of the interface?** I have seen this:  [blog]: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/moxy-jaxb-map-interfaces-to-xml.html#comment-form

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I wrote xml-elementS to enhance the view of the S letter because there are two tags `<xml-elements>` and inside that  `<xml-element>` without s letter :)

Answer (score 2):

You aren't permitted to have an `<xml-element-wrapper>` per `<xml-element>` inside an `<xml-elements>` in terms of what MOXy will process.  You could have a single `<xml-element-wrapper` inside of `<xml-elements>`.

**oxm.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings 
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="forum16943280" 
    xml-mapping-metadata-complete="true">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="SearchResult">
            <xml-root-element/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-elements java-attribute="results">
                    <xml-element name="GaDictionaryElement" type="forum16943280.GaDictionary"/>
                    <xml-element name="OrganizationUnitElement" type="forum16943280.OrganizationUnit"/>
                    <xml-element-wrapper name="results"/>
                </xml-elements>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

**SearchResult**

```java
package forum16943280;

import java.util.List;

public class SearchResult {

    private List<Object> results;

    public List<Object> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(List<Object> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

}
```

**GaDictionary**

```java
package forum16943280;

public class GaDictionary {

}
```

**OrganizationUnit**

```java
package forum16943280;

public class OrganizationUnit {

}
```

**Demo**

```java
package forum16943280;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String , Object>();
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, "forum16943280/oxm.xml");
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {SearchResult.class}, properties);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum16943280/input.xml");
        SearchResult result = (SearchResult) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(result, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<searchResult>
   <results>
      <OrganizationUnitElement/>
      <OrganizationUnitElement/>
   </results>
</searchResult>
```

**input.xml/Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<searchResult>
   <results>
      <GaDictionaryElement/>
      <GaDictionaryElement/>
   </results>
</searchResult>
```

Comment: _It may work better for your use case to have separate lists properties each annotated with `<xml-element>` with its own `<xml-element-wrapper>`._ Could you explain me ? I should obtain a different name of wrapper for each type that I get. Because the `List<?> results` contains element always of the same type E.g. `type=it.ga.model.GaDictionary` or `it.ga.model.OrganizationUnit` and so on... So if my `List<?> results` is empty I pass to the marshaller an `JaxbSearchResult` istance with a results  property as `new ArrayList<TypeThatIWantToSeeAsEmptyTag>` One of the specified above. :)

Comment: I tried your solution and this is the answer `The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup` It doesn't work :(

Comment: @Sergio - From that exception it sounds as though the XML is not well formed.  Can you check that the XML is valid.

Comment: Without that tag `<xml-element-wrapper/>` it works. In my next answer I wrote input xml file and output that the marshaller produces

Comment: @Sergio - I have updated this answer with a more complete example.  I have also added a new answer with the multiple list approach:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16965114/383861

Answer (score 1):

If you want separate element wrappers you could split the `results` property up per type.

**SearchResult**

```java
package forum16943280;

import java.util.List;

public class SearchResult {

    private List<GaDictionary> gaDictionaryResults;
    private List<OrganizationUnit> organizationUnitResults;

    public List<GaDictionary> getGaDictionaryResults() {
        return gaDictionaryResults;
    }

    public void setGaDictionaryResults(List<GaDictionary> results) {
        this.gaDictionaryResults = results;
    }

    public List<OrganizationUnit> getOrganizationUnitResults() {
        return organizationUnitResults;
    }

    public void setOrganizationUnitResults(
            List<OrganizationUnit> organizationUnitResults) {
        this.organizationUnitResults = organizationUnitResults;
    }

}
```

**oxm.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings 
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="forum16943280" 
    xml-mapping-metadata-complete="true">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="SearchResult">
            <xml-root-element/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element 
                    java-attribute="gaDictionaryResults"
                    name="GaDictionaryElement">
                    <xml-element-wrapper name="GaDictionaryElementWrapper"/>
                </xml-element>
                <xml-element 
                    java-attribute="organizationUnitResults"
                    name="OrganizationUnitElement">
                    <xml-element-wrapper name="OrganizationUnitElementWrapper"/>
                </xml-element>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

**Demo**

```java
package forum16943280;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String , Object>();
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, "forum16943280/oxm.xml");
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {SearchResult.class}, properties);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum16943280/input.xml");
        SearchResult result = (SearchResult) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(result, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<searchResult>
   <GaDictionaryElementWrapper>
      <GaDictionaryElement/>
      <GaDictionaryElement/>
   </GaDictionaryElementWrapper>
</searchResult>
```

**input.xml/Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<searchResult>
   <OrganizationUnitElementWrapper>
      <OrganizationUnitElement/>
      <OrganizationUnitElement/>
   </OrganizationUnitElementWrapper>
</searchResult>
```

Comment: Are you able to produce it in Json and remove the initial starting of a List type as `[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"}]` and not in this way `{  "results" : [ { [{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"}] }` ? I tried by putting in the properties the option JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT False but I need to remove the name of the element not only the root! Unluckly I'm manipulating the String manually to get the result that I want :(

Comment: @Sergio - If you marshal a `List` directly it will marshal as a top-level JSON array.

Comment: Good but my List is `List<?>` and it give me also the type="Person" in the json results! `[{"type" : "person","id":"1"},{"type" : "person","id":"2"}] }`

Comment: **I don't want the "type of the object"** Which is the option to avoid that it marshal and display "type" too?

Comment: @Sergio - Can you start a new question for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966861/moxy-marshal-list-how-to-avoid-that-it-shows-the-type-in-json-results Done

Comment: Thank you really much for your time but I thought a better solution. I can't avoid to use `?` type because the type of a web module is not knowed from the other so my SearchResult class doesn't know the other type. I'm creating using the multipleBinding concept different binding files. So depending on the class that is retrieved I will use a different binding file in a way that I can split in xml files the binding. If I Haven't  been clear I will put the code once that I finished. Could you let me know if you have an answer for my second question about that I typed in bold? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="it.core.widget.dto" xml-mapping-metadata-complete="true">
    <xml-schema element-form-default="QUALIFIED" />
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="JaxbSearchResult" xml-accessor-type="NONE">
            <xml-root-element />
            <xml-type prop-order="count pageSize requestParameters sortDirection results" />
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="count" />
                <xml-element java-attribute="requestParameters" />
                <xml-element java-attribute="pageSize" />
                <xml-element java-attribute="sortDirection" />
                <xml-elements java-attribute="results">
                    <xml-element name="gaDictionaryElement" type="it.ga.model.GaDictionary" />
                    <xml-element name="organizationUnitElement" type="it.ga.model.OrganizationUnit" />
                    <xml-element name="personElement" type="it.ga.model.Person" />
                    <xml-element-wrapper />
                </xml-elements>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

This is the xml and works if I remove `<xml-element-wrapper />`

Furthermore without that tag it produces the above output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxbSearchResult>
    <count>3</count>
    <pageSize>30</pageSize>
    <style>1</style>
    <discriminator>equipment</discriminator>
    <posting>1</posting>
    <CLEAR>1</CLEAR>
    <sortDirection> ASC </sortDirection>
    <gaDictionaryElement>
        <id>24964</id>
        <startDate>2013-03-12T00:00:00</startDate>
        <gaDictionaryMap />
        <booleanMap />
        <integerMap />
        <numberMap />
        <clobMap />
        <parentGaDictionaryLinkSet />
        <childGaDictionaryLinkSet />
        <displayValue>Equipment 2</displayValue>
    </gaDictionaryElement>
    <gaDictionaryElement>
        <id>24962</id>
        <startDate>2013-03-12T00:00:00</startDate>
        <gaDictionaryMap />
        <booleanMap />
        <integerMap />
        <numberMap />
        <clobMap />
        <parentGaDictionaryLinkSet />
        <childGaDictionaryLinkSet />
        <displayValue>Equipment 1</displayValue>
    </gaDictionaryElement>
    <gaDictionaryElement>
        <id>25185</id>
        <startDate>2013-04-22T00:00:00</startDate>
        <gaDictionaryMap />
        <booleanMap />
        <integerMap />
        <numberMap />
        <clobMap />
        <parentGaDictionaryLinkSet />
        <childGaDictionaryLinkSet />
        <displayValue>Attrezzatura test</displayValue>
    </gaDictionaryElement>
</jaxbSearchResult>
```

I need to wrap gaDictionaryElement accordingly the type that has been marshalled.
Any help is appreciated.
**Furthermore did someone try to create a binding file that could be useful for classes that implements a particular interface? E.g. In a way that I can see only the property of the object defined on the binding file and specifying as type the name of the interface? I have seen this:** [blog]: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/moxy-jaxb-map-interfaces-to-xml.html#comment-form

Comment: I tried also adding the encoding="UTF-8" but it doesn't work with that tag `<xml-element-wrapper />`