# MOXy marshal List<?> how to avoid that it shows the type in json results?

Tags: json, eclipselink, moxy

If I have to marshal a `List<?>` how to avoid that it shows the type?

So the result of a marshalling  `List<?>` is `[{"type" : "person","id":"1"},{"type" : "person","id":"2"}] }` and it give me also the type="Person" in the JSON results!

How could I avoid that it shows me the type?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to reproduce the issue that you are seeing.  Below is what I have tried.

**Domain Model (Person)**

```java
package forum16966861;

public class Person {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html).

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

```java
package forum16966861;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Person.class}, properties);

        List<Object> people = new ArrayList<Object>(2);

        Person jane = new Person();
        jane.setId(1);
        jane.setName("Jane");
        people.add(jane);

        Person john = new Person();
        john.setId(2);
        john.setName("John");
        people.add(john);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(people, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
[ {
   "id" : 1,
   "name" : "Jane"
}, {
   "id" : 2,
   "name" : "John"
} ]
```

---

**UPDATE**

> I don't have right now the code but I can see that the difference is
>   that I define a metadata xml file where I say how to bind Person.

I still haven't reproduced your issue, but here is how I have adapted my example.

**oxm.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="forum16966861">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="Person">
            <xml-root-element/>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

**Demo**

```java
package forum16966861;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(3);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, "forum16966861/oxm.xml");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("forum16966861", Person.class.getClassLoader(), properties);

        List<Object> people = new ArrayList<Object>(2);

        Person jane = new Person();
        jane.setId(1);
        jane.setName("Jane");
        people.add(jane);

        Person john = new Person();
        john.setId(2);
        john.setName("John");
        people.add(john);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(people, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
[ {
   "id" : 1,
   "name" : "Jane"
}, {
   "id" : 2,
   "name" : "John"
} ]
```

Comment: I don't have right now the code but I can see that the difference is that I define a metadata xml file where I say how to bind Person. I have already defined inside the package where is my model class jaxb.properties. You have been really gentle! Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: @Sergio - I still haven't reproduced your issue, but I have updated my answer based on your comment.  I'm happy to help, I'm Canadian so I have to be gentle :).

Comment: Try this: `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="forum16966861">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="Person" xml-accessor-type="NONE">
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="id" />
                <xml-element java-attribute="name" />
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>`

Comment: @Sergio - I get the same output I posted in my answer.  If you run the code from my answer what output do you get?

Comment: Unluckly I don't have my environment in this machine here it's evening and I will try tomorrow morning. However thank you it's really weird so if you get the same result It's really frustating...because the property type isn't present in my model class! So I don't understand how it can put it to the result! Couldn't we chat on google+ tomorrow?

Comment: @Sergio - That may work, I'm in the eastern time zone.  My google+ info is on my blog:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31353/discussion-between-sergio-and-blaise-doughan)